# IIS 6 Parameterized Redirects

Tags: redirect, iis-6

It looks like there's a way to, in IIS 6, do the following: 
Redirect http://mydomain.com/old_page.asp?oldparam=111 to http://mydomain.com/new-page/111

But, I'm not sure how best to achieve this.

I'm reading up about using VBScript to access the MetaBase to set this up as shown on this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525728%28v=vs.90%29.aspx, but so far I've had no luck. The documentation seems to assume and advanced user... I need something a little more novice. 
(Also you seem to be able to use the Active Directory version or WMI version in VBS - I don't know either of them)

Any ideas?

Regards,
Jacques